# Can 2 circuits exist and work independantly in an electric guitar

Tags: circuit-design

An electric guitar typically has 1 circuit for the pick ups, and mixing active (powered by a battery) pick ups with passive pick ups (no battery) appears to be not possible on 1 circuit.

I am trying to do understand if it is possible if you have 2 circuits though.

[image]

I'm not an electrical engineer, but I am hoping the diagram above gives an indiciation on what I'm trying to achieve. The 2 circuits are split by colour (light blue and light green).

The light green are active and require a battery, each pick up has a tone pot and both active pick ups share the same volume. The active pick ups also have a 3 way switch to blend the sound from 1 or both pick ups.

The light blue is my passive pick up. It has it's own dedicated volume control.

The 2 circuits share nothing in common, other than the switch.

Does the 'circuit' I've drawn make sense? Or is there a reason why this would not be possible

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You just need a bypass switch. You would probably want to disconnect the pickup from the input to the preamp as well, as electric guitar pickups are sensitive to loading. That isn't hard to achieve though:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2F42o.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Rather simplified "preamp" with no gain, DC blocking caps or other components shown - just the 1M resistor which sets the input impedance, and is disconnected with the preamp switched out.)

Comment: If the active pickup has a low-impedance output, you could add a resistor to the output of the op amp and mix it with the output from the active pickup.